# ¿Como hacer un virtualHost desde un contenedor docker?

Tags: linux, docker, apache2, virtualhost

les agradezco me puedan ayudar con este problema, como bien digo en el titulo estoy tratando de hacer un virtualHost desde un contenedor en docker, les voy a dar los paso paso que llevo hasta el momento de instalar apache2.

creo mi carpeta que va contener el proyecto por ahora solo un archivo index.html

```
mkdir /var/www/actividades-js
```

Seguido agrego algunas lineas HTML para que tenga contenido

cambio los permisos de propietario del directorio

```
chown -R www-data: /var/www/actividades-js
```

Creo el virtualHost

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/actividades-js.conf
```

Y dentro del archivo creado coloco el siguiente contenido

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName actividades.local.dev
    ServerAlias www.actividades.local.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/actividades-js
 
    <Directory /var/www/actividades-js>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/actividades.local.dev-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/actividades.local.dev-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Lo siguiente activo el sitio con el siguiente comando

```
 a2ensite actividades-js.conf
```

desactivo el host por defecto con el siguiente comando

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Ahora en mi equipo Laptop agrego ese host para que lo reconozca ingresando con el siguiente comando

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

Y dentro del archivo coloco la siguiente linea

```
172.17.0.12      actividades.local.dev
```

por ultimo reinicio el apache
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Eso es todo lo que he hecho hasta el momento y cuando voy a mi navegador y escribo http://www.actividades.local.dev

esto es lo que se ve en el navegador
[image: vista desde el navegador]

Espero que alguien me ayude a resolver este problema, muchas gracias por su colaboración.

EDICIÓN:

Ahora si ingreso a la ip que me da el contenedor para ver en el navegador 172.17.0.2 me hace el enlace al archivo del actividades-js.conf obvio desabilite el por defecto 000-default.conf y puedo ver el archivo index que esta en esa carpeta, pero si ingreso con el dominio que le coloque me sale otro mensaje distinto al anterior en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que cambie el nombre del dominio virtual por solo local.dev

No se si esta captura de las características de mi contenedor sirvan de algo, adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Expusiste el puerto del contenedor?

Comment: Hola Benjamin, no! y como lo puedo hacer ?

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que sea porque los puertos no están expuestos, para exponer un puerto se utiliza la siguiente opción al ejecutar `docker run`:

```
-p, --publish ip:[hostPort]:containerPort | [hostPort:]containerPort
```

De las páginas del manual:

> Publish a container's port, or range of ports, to the host.

Así que si por ejemplo, quiero que en la máquina *host* se escuche en el puerto `2589` y que se haga una redirección del tráfico entrante en ese puerto del *host* al puerto `789` del contenedor tendría que escribir `docker run <nombre de la imagen> --publish 2589:789`.

Por otro lado si quiero poner un servidor HTTP a la escucha de peticiones en el puerto `80` para ambos, host y contenedor, escuchando únicamente en una IP (digamos `192.168.1.45`) puedo escribir `docker run <nombre de la imagen> --publish 192.168.1.45:80:80`.

Si simplemente quiero hacer un bind a `0.0.0.0` (que resulta en la escucha en cualquier IP) del puerto `80` del host al puerto `80` del contenedor puedo simplemente escribir `docker run <nombre de la imagen> --publish 80`.

Sin embargo, se pueden hacer más cosas, revisa la [documentación](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) para más información

Comment: Hola Benjamin, gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de probar lo siguiente, empece desde cero otro contenedor y cree el siguiente comando.
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /home/$USER/www-local:/var/www/ --name my_server -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash ....

Lo unico diferente fue que en mi archivo hosts local puse la siguiente linea 172.12.0.2  actividades.local.dev:8080...
También en el archivo del host Virtual del contenedor agregue ese mismo puerto en la primera linea de la siguiente forma <VirtualHost *:8080> ..
Pero cuando ingreso al sitio con el dominio virtual que le dí no me funciona

Comment: @CristhianMolina `172.12.0.2` es la IP de la subred de docker me imagino, pero intentaste acceder directamente al puerto `8080` con tu red local o con localhost? A final de cuentas para eso es la redirección, tampoco estoy seguro que en el archivo hosts se correcto poner el puerto `8080`, pues ahí se tratan únicamente hosts

Comment: Claro la ip ´172.12.0.2´ es la ip que me provee Apache cuando lo corro con el siguiente mensaje (apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message). he intentado acceder con esa IP y colocandole el puerto 8080 y no deja ver nada, pero si solo coloco esa IP si me muestra, pero aún sin conseguir el resultado colocando el host virtual

Comment: En el archivo host de mi maquina local ya le quite ese 8080 a la ip

Comment: @CristhianMolina, si ya te aceptó peticiones en el puerto `80` (cuando pusiste la IP) quizá no sea problema de exposición de puertos (a menos que hayas hecho algo raro o tengas un firewall) sino de la configuración de apache